# Increase speed with each enemy destroyed?

Tags: unity, c#

I need some help with coding this idea: "For each Target destroyed, increase the Gunner's speed by (speed variable)". The idea is that the Gunner is automatically moving, and I want it to become more frantic with each target hit.

Here's the relevant code I have so far:

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

    void Update () {
            Gunner_Move (); 
    }


    //gives me the error "Assets/_Scripts/MovementPathScript.cs(60,83): error CS0200: Property or indexer `System.Array.Length' cannot be assigned to (it is read only)"
    void Gunner_Move(){
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("BulletProgressionObject").Length -= 1)
                Gunner_SpeedIncrease ();
    }
```

void Gunner_SpeedIncrease(){
         //behavior that I'm not sure how to make
   }

```
    //for the bullets colliding with target's parent object
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("BulletProgressionObject"))
                Destroy (other.gameObject);
```

I think it's a foreach loop, but the issue I'm having is properly implementing it. Any suggestions or referrals would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The line `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("BulletProgressionObject").Length -= 1` means "decrease the array length by one" which obviously doesn't make sense because 1. array lengths are read-only, 2. it's a temporary array generated on-the-fly by `FindGameObjectsWithTag ` and 3. it's in an if-condition and assignments in if-conditions are not allowed. What do you *really* want to do in that line? What's a `BulletProgressionObject` anyway?

Comment: It's comprised of a Target and Laser Gate. The Bullet can pass through the Laser Gate, but the Gunner can't. BulletProgressionObject is just an arbitrary name I gave the parent game object.

Comment: OK, and why are you counting how many of these you have in the scene and then try to decrease their count by one?

Comment: You are dodging the question. Is what you are actually trying to do *in that line* is count how many of these objects you still have in the scene and then set the speed accordingly? In that case I would expect that `Gunner_SpeedIncrease` is called `Gunner_SetSpeed` and takes a number as an argument.

Comment: Not dodging, just misunderstood. Anyway, yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than calling `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` every frame, you could just call `Gunner_SpeedIncrease()` within `OnTriggerEnter` when the trigger/collision happens.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("BulletProgressionObject")) {
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
        Gunner_SpeedIncrease ();
    }
}
```